# Can someone explain the flow of steps that are happening here?

Tags: javascript, maps, reduce

I'm trying to figure out is each item going through reduce as the map runs, or is the map method running completely, and then after it returns the array, the reduce method is being applied to the array from the map?

```
 const lineItems = [
{ description: 'Eggs (Dozen)', quantity: 1, price: 3, total: 3 },
{ description: 'Cheese', quantity: 0.5, price: 5, total: 2.5 },
{ description: 'Butter', quantity: 2, price: 6, total: 12 }
];

let store = lineItems.map(item => item.quantity).reduce(sumReducer, 0);

function sumReducer(sum, val) {
  return sum += val;
}

console.log(store);
```

Comment: The ``.map`` returns an array of the quantities (``[1, 0.5, 2]``). After that, we use ``.reduce`` on the later to get the sum of these numbers. One way to understand this more is to split the steps into separate variables and see the results.

Comment: If you use `sum + val.quantity`, you don't need the `map` (unless you want a generic `sumReducer`)

Comment: this is called a chaining (of methods)

Comment: simply do `let store = lineItems.reduce((sum,el)=>sum+el.quantity, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

All regular - non generator - functions in javascript have run-to-completion semantics. This means that when they are called, the execute until they return without interruption.

In this case the *map()* function executes and returns an array, then the *reduce()* function executes.